# Add a join key to a group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating an app to store game results between friends. In my app groups will be called Leagues.

To keep the leagues private I'd like to add a join key to it. When a league is created the creator chooses a join key. Later other users can join by choosing a league from a dropdown and filling in the exact join key. The user can only if the join key matches the selected league.

Controller:

```
 def edit
        @user = User.find(current_user.id)
        @league_list =  League.all.map{|l| [ l.league_name, l.id ] }
  #      @league_keys = League.all.map{|l| [ l.join_key, l.id ] }
    end

    def update
        @user = User.find(current_user.id)

        if @user.update(user_join_league_params) #&& @league_list.league_id == @league_keys.league_id
            @user.save
            redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Successfully joined this league!"
        else
            render 'index'
        end
    end
```

As you can see I have to edit the users league_id to complete the join.

View:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px; text-align:center">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                JOIN A LEAGUE
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>

                <%= f.select(:league_id, @league_list) %><br> <br>

              #  <%= f.input_field :join_key %><br> <br>

                <p>!! Watch out this cannot be changed after !!</p>

                <br> <br> <%= f.submit "Join league", class: "btn-submit" %>
                <% end %>


      </div>
</div>
```

So I'd like this form to only perform the update action if the selected league matches the filled in key.

I've been looking for an answer in numerous posts on stackoverflow but I couldn't find a post with a simular issue.

How can I get this done?

EDIT:

Relations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :league
end

class League < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :games
    has_many :multiplayergames
    has_many :users
end
```

SECOND EDIT:

So I've tried to implement the solloution.

I was using simple_form for <%= f.select(:league_id, @league_list) %>

I tried to do it like this:

```
<%= form_tag(user_path(@user), method: :put) do %>
   <%= select_tag :league_id, options_for_select(@league_list) %><br> <br>

                <p>Join Key</p>
    <%= text_field_tag :join_key %><br> <br>
   <p>!! Watch out this cannot be changed after !!</p>

   <br> <br> <%= submit_tag "Join league", class: "btn-submit" %>
<% end %>
```

However this gives the error:

> param is missing or the value is empty: user

THIRD EDIT:

Controller:

```
# JOIN A LEAGUE

    def edit
        @user = User.find(current_user.id)
        @league_list =  League.all.map{|l| [ l.league_name, l.id ] }

    end

    def update
        @user = User.find(current_user.id)
        @league = League.find_by_id(params[:league_id])

        if @league.join_key == params[:join_key] && @user.update(user_join_league_params)

           redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Successfully joined this league!"
        else
            redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user), notice: "Could not join league check if join key is correct!"
        end
end

 def user_join_league_params

        params.permit!(:league_id,:join_key)
end
```

VIEW:

```
<%= form_tag(user_path(@user), method: :put) do %>

                <%= select_tag :league_id, options_for_select(@league_list, :league_id) %><br> <br>

                        <p>Join Key</p>

                <%= text_field_tag :join_key %><br> <br>

                <p>!! Watch out this cannot be changed after !!</p>

            <br> <br> <%= submit_tag "Join league", class: "btn-submit" %>

        <% end %>
```

Comment: what is relationship between this model?

Comment: I've added the relations from the models concerning the leagues

Comment: So you have leagues with join keys and you want the user to input the join key of that league which the user want to join. If so how the user gets to know the join key that he has to input in the form?

Comment: The creator of the league has to choose the join_key. After they send the join key to their friends via sms, facebook, ... 

The goal is to only let friends join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` action can look as follows:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @league = League.find_by_id(params[:league_id])
    if @league.join_key == params[:join_key] && @user.update(league_id: params[:league_id])
       redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Successfully joined this league!"
    else
       render 'index'
    end
end
```

form can look as follows:

```
<%= form_tag(user_path(@user), method: :put) do %>
   <%= select_tag :league_id, options_for_select(@league_list) %><br> <br>
   <%= text_field_tag :join_key %><br> <br>
   <p>!! Watch out this cannot be changed after !!</p>
   <br> <br> <%= submit_tag "Join league", class: "btn-submit" %>
<% end %>
```

*Note*: I have assumed `join_key` is an attribute in your `League` model.
Make sure you pass `params` accordingly in your `user_join_league_params`.

**Edit:**

Your should permit your params:

```
def user_join_league_params
  params.permit!(:league_id,:join_key)
end
```

Comment: There is no `input_field_tag` in rails.

Comment: Also you need to remove `@user.save`.

Comment: Join key is indeed an attribute from Leagues.
I'm getting an error though:
param is missing or the value is empty: user

I'm assuming I still have to pass the params accordingly like you said in the note but I'm not really sure how to do this

Comment: @dkp do you know the problem here?

Comment: @LouisDeBeule I have edited the form and added the strong param method in the answer. Please give it a try.

Comment: @dkp now its saying :

wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)

Comment: @LouisDeBeule can you check what comes in `params` when you submit the form ?

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"RmMz5xPK1/4DZwn9eB3cHiPpcjTUiCbXlyLFJKAxbZQl6qvyxmPL0qnnaCEtNkfDWN8lx/VKg4q84BCW9/yAsQ==",
 "league_id"=>"1",
 "join_key"=>"stanistinkt",
 "commit"=>"Join league",
 "id"=>"17"}

Comment: @LouisDeBeule can you just cross check your strong param method name and what method you have used in update action. `user_join_league_params` - name of strong param method. So, in `update action` it should be `@user.update(user_join_league_params)`

Comment: I've edited the question with my code now, the strong param name is correct I think...

Comment: @LouisDeBeule    `if @league.join_key == params[:join_key] && @user.update(league_id: params[:league_id])` - just change this. you do not need `join_key` for `User`.